# cannot enable html text field. IE 8 issue. firefox works fine

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8

If I use the dom and try `alert(field.getAttribute("disabled"));` I get a false even when the filter field is showing disabled and I cannot click on the text field. However if I use IE Developer Tools, I get

I am seeing no disabled field in this one.

Not sure what is causing the field to be disabled. I have looked at css files and have not seen anything obvious. Tried looking at visibility, readonly attributes and did not help.
Not sure what else I could try. Screens are bindows based but specifically the screen I am rendering is using a jsp file.

Comment: post your code, is it readonly?

Answer (score 0):

try: `alert(field.disabled);`
to enable: `field.disabled = false;`
to disable: `field.disabled = true;`

Hope this helps.

Comment: hmm... you could also try to set the disabled attribute manualy and see what happens when your code is invoked. It would also be nice if you could post your code that we can see where the error lies.

Comment: forgot to mention that tabbing to the field works (makes the field enabled) but I also tried field.removeAttribute("readonly")

Comment: I'm afraid but without a reference to the website or a sniplet I can't help you any further.